# How to call String method on empty interface directly?

Tags: go

The only solution I know is using `fmt.Sprint` or similar functions. I already look into `builtin` package but it has only `error` interface, `string` is just a normal type, not interface.

Comment: What is your goal? Is it calling [stringer](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Stringer) interface? can you provide specific?

Comment: @jeevatkm stringer is what I'm looking for. Thank you! I think calling `fmt.Sprint` is not an elegant way.

Comment: You cannot as the empty interface has _no_ methods.

Comment: @Volker What I mean is type assertion it to `Stringer` interface, then call `String()` directly.

Comment: Then the title is pretty misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @volker mentioned; you cannot as the empty interface has no methods.

*Please note: `fmt.Sprint`, `fmt.Sprintf` etc. does call Stringer interface first if its exists. It is elegant way.*

Example of calling stringer interface after type assertion.

```
var a SomeType
if v, ok := a.(fmt.Stringer); ok {
    fmt.Println(v.String())
}
```